# Python: How can I sort in outputting .csv files?

Tags: list, csv

Linked is my project that I am working on.

Link to what this project is about:https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnuHD.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuFBe.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/12CcT.png

I have already completed some of the program. However, I am having trouble on doing part b, which is asking me to create an output file for each major and add the students that are in that major.
Here is my current code:

```
student_major_file = 'StudentsMajorsList.csv'
gpa_file = 'GPAList.csv'
graduation_file = 'GraduationDatesList.csv'

with open(student_major_file) as file1:
    list1 = file1.read().splitlines()

with open(gpa_file) as file2:
    list2 = file2.read().splitlines()

with open(graduation_file) as file3:
    list3 = file3.read().splitlines()
output1 = open('FullRoster.csv', 'w')
output3 = open('ScholarshipCandidates.csv', 'w')
output4 = open('DisciplinedStudents.csv', 'w')

#part a
for a, b, c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    x = a.split(',')
    y = b.split(',')
    z = c.split(',')

    output1.write(x[0] + ', ' + x[2] + ', ' + y[-1] + ', ' + 
    x[1] + ', ' + z[-1] + ', ' + x[4])
    output1.write('\n')

#part b

#part c
for a, b, c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    x = a.split(',')
    y = b.split(',')
    z = c.split(',')

    if float(b[-1]) > 3.8:
        output3.write(x[0] + ', ' + x[1] + ', ' + x[2] + ', ' + 
        z[-1])
        output3.write('\n')


    
#part d
for a, b, c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    x = a.split(',')
    y = b.split(',')
    z = c.split(',')

    if a[-1] == 'Y':
        output4.write(x[0] + ', ' + x[1] + ', ' + x[2] + ', ' + 
        z[-1])
        output4.write('\n')


output1.close()     
output3.close()
output4.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't give a more straightforward answer because I couldn't deduce your case (what is your input data, and what exactly do you want to output) from your question. But please accept some suggestions:
1. structure your sequence of statements in order you only start something after the previous requisite is done  - for instance, don't open your output files before your output data is ready to be dumped. 2. name your variables meaningfully, instead of using single letters or cryptic acronyms. Then you'll see you must sort the structured data you built from your input, and then dump it to csv.

Comment: @VBobCat Thanks for your reply! I added more imgur links for input and output.

Comment: Well, I see your problem. The input files bring students in different orders. So there's no escape for putting some effort in deserializing and reorganizing your data. There's many ways to do it but I would start loading only your first file and converting it in a list of dicts, each one with a key (id,first name,etc) and the corresponding value. For the next files, I would retrieve the dict corresponding to the student and add the new fields as key-value pairs. From that you can finally iterate your list of dicts and prepare your output data.